# (SML) Defining a type as a function and creating a function of this type

Tags: sml, smlnj

First question here and just want to preface that I did several queries and while I found multiple questions that were worded similarly I found none that were asking, or answering, the question I have (as far as I can tell).

I'm working in SML on an assignment for class so I'm going to leave some details out so I can resolve the issue myself. I have the following type defined in SML:

```
- type Env = string -> int;
```

Essentially, the Env type is supposed to be a function that allows mapping from a string to an int - it's a simple environment scheme. It is trivial enough to create a function that does this, i.e.:

```
- fun foo (s:string) = 10; (*simple example*)
```

But is there a way to actually declare this function as a "Env type"? The reason is eventually I need to create a function whose return value is an Env type function and I have no idea how to perform this. I'm aware SML allows type aliasing and I think this means that technically any function which has the type `string -> int` would be synonymous with the Env type to the program, but I would like something more explicit.

If clarification is needed please ask and I will attempt to be more concise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The reason is eventually I need to create a function whose return value is an Env type function and I have no idea how to perform this.

When using `fun`, you can specify that the return-type is `Env` by putting the type annotation `: Env` after all of the argument-patterns; for example:

```
fun fooFactory arg : Env = ...
```

Comment: While some of the answers below are insightful and explanatory I appreciate the conciseness of this one. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `val` binding rather than a `fun` declaration to get SML to explicitly associate the type with the function. Either a two-step process like this:

```
- fun foo_temp (s:string) = 10;
val foo_temp = fn : string -> int

- val foo:Env = foo_temp;
val foo = fn : Env
```

Or you could use an anonymous function:

```
 -val (foo:Env) = fn (s:string) => 10;
val foo = fn : Env
```

I'm not sure if it is possible to do it directly using the `fun` keyword. For example, the following fails:

```
-fun (foo:Env) (s:string) = 10;
```

with the somewhat cryptic message `Error: illegal function symbol in clause`

Perhaps there is some other workaround that I am not familiar with

Comment: +1. Note that in the `foo_temp` case, you should probably use `local` (and can even use the name `foo`). Also note that in the anonymous-function case, you will need to use `val rec` if the function is recursive. Lastly, note that you could accomplish approximately the same thing by putting `val _ = foo : Env` on the following line.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Env` is just a type alias (being created using `type Env = ...` rather than e.g. `datatype Env = ...` or `abstype Env = ...`), creating a function that returns an `Env` is exactly the same as creating a function that returns a *string → int* function.

Here are two interpretations of your question:

> How do I create a function that returns a *string → int* function?

There are several ways, it really depends on what it should be doing. But some examples could be:

```
val zero_env = fn s => 0
fun update_env env t x = fn s => if s = t then x else env s
fun add_env env t x = fn s => env s + (if s = t then x else 0)
```

> How do I ensure that the type signature explicitly says *... → Env* rather than *... string → int*?

1. Use `datatype Env = ...`:

   ```
   datatype Env = Env of string -> int
   fun unEnv (Env f) = f
   val zero_env = Env (fn s => 0)
   fun update_env env t x = Env (fn s => if s = t then x else (unEnv env) s)
   fun add_env env t x = Env (fn s => (unEnv env) s + (if s = t then x else 0))
   ```
2. Use `abstype Env = ...`:

   ```
   abstype Env = Env of string -> int
   with
       (* ... same as e.g. type Env = ..., except now the Env type is opaque ... *)
   end
   ```
3. Use modules:

   ```
   signature ENV =
   sig
       type Env
       val zero_env : Env
       val update_env : Env -> string -> int -> Env
       val add_env : Env -> string -> int -> Env
       ...
   end

   structure FunctionalEnv : ENV =
   struct
       (* ... same as e.g. type Env = ..., except now the Env type is opaque ... *)
   end
   ```